# How to justify a report?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting

I want the following layout. What change should I make to get the desired output?

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

    %adjust your page margins here
    \usepackage[top=0.70in, bottom=0.70in, left=0.8in,right=0.80in]{geometry} % setting the page alignment with this package
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} %for embedding images
    \usepackage[%dvips, % commented for pdflatex
    bookmarks,  colorlinks=false]{hyperref} %for creating links in the pdf version and other additional pdf attributes, no effect on the printed document
    %\hypersetup{%
        %pdfborder = {0 0 0}
    %}
    \usepackage[final]{pdfpages} %for embedding another pdf, remove if not required
    \usepackage{float} %used for figure placement with H as a parameter
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{pslatex} % for times new roman, old package, but works
    \usepackage{array} % for making text bold in table
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{enumerate}
    \usepackage{longtable}

    \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
    \def\figurename{\textbf{Figure }}

    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{color}

    \definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
    \definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
    \definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

    \lstset{ %
      language=Java,                % the language of the code
      basicstyle=\footnotesize,           % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
      numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
      numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},  % the style that is used for the line-numbers
      stepnumber=1,                   % each line is numbered
      numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
      backgroundcolor=\color{white},      % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
      showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
      showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
      showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
      frame=single,                   % adds a frame around the code
      rulecolor=\color{black},        % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. commens (green here))
      tabsize=2,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
      captionpos=b,                   % sets the caption-position to bottom
      breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
      breakatwhitespace=false,        % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
      title=\lstname,                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting;
                                      % also try caption instead of title
      keywordstyle=\color{blue},          % keyword style
      commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},       % comment style
      stringstyle=\color{mauve},         % string literal style
      escapeinside={\%*}{*)},            % if you want to add a comment within your code
      morekeywords={*,...}               % if you want to add more keywords to the set
    }

    %For the header and footer
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[L]{\emph{Fr.C.Rodrigues Institute of Technology, Vashi}} % except the center
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    }

    \pagestyle{fancy}

    \rhead{\emph{NAME OF PROJECT}}

    \fancyfoot[LO,LE]{\emph{Department of Electronics and Tlecommunication, FCRIT,Vashi}}
    \cfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RO, RE]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    %For the header and footer Over

    %Page Border
    \usepackage{pgf}
    \usepackage{pgfpages}

    \pgfpagesdeclarelayout{boxed}
    {
      \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
    }
    {
      \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
      {%
        logical pages=1,%
      }
      \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
      {
        border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\pgfstroke,%
        border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
        resized width=.95\pgfphysicalwidth,%
        resized height=.95\pgfphysicalheight,%
        center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
      }%
    }
    %\pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}
    \setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
    %GLOBAL SETTINGS OVER, DOCUMENT BEGINS

    \begin{document}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\lhead{ }

%FROM HERE YOUR PAGES START GETTING ADDED

% includes the cover page
\input{project/cover.tex}
\newpage

\input{project/title.tex}
\newpage

% includes the certificate page
\input{project/certificate.tex} 
\newpage

% includes the acknowledgements page
\input{project/acknowledgements.tex} 
\newpage

\input{project/abstract.tex} % adds the Research Methodology page
\newpage

%TABLE OF CONTENTS AND LIST OF FIGURES ARE AUTOMATICALLY ADDED BY FOLLOWING COMMANDS
%ADD FIGURE OF TABLES IF YOU NEED TO, CHECK DOCUMENTATION
\pagenumbering{roman} %numbering before main content starts


%To reset the Header & Footer for TOC and LOF
\pagestyle{empty}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\tableofcontents % adds Index Page

\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\listoffigures % adds List of Figures
\cleardoublepage

%And reset back the settings we choose for Header and Footer
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} %reset numbering to normal for the main content

\input{project/introduction.tex} % adds the introduction page
\input{project/literature-survey.tex} % adds the Literature Survey page
\input{project/srs.tex}
\input{project/req-analysis.tex}
\input{project/system-design.tex}
\input{
project/testing.tex}
\input{project/planning.tex}
\input{project/implementation.tex} % adds the Project Design
\input{project/screenshots.tex}
\input{project/conclusion.tex} % adds the Scheduling and Planning page
\input{project/ref.tex} % adds the References page

\end{document}
```

The `Introduction.tex` contains this

```
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\section{BACKGROUND}
%\subsection{SUBSECTION NAME 1}
\paragraph{} Researchermvlcvmxcv ..................
```

I want the paragraph to be fully justified. However the output that i get is hown below.

[image]

Comment: This is the default for report. If you need centered chapter titles, that can easily be modified. I prefer patching, some would recommend package titlesec.

Comment: Justified paragraphs are the default in LaTeX.

Comment: If this is about the vertical skip between paragraphs, package parskip

Comment: I tried using \raggedright. But it is not getting justified.

Comment: Of course not, you demand a ragged right margin (i.e. lines should not be filled with extra whitespace), so that's what you get.

Comment: Kitty, \raggedright would make the text ragged right. The text is justified by default, something in your document changes that. We cannot know what that might be. Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: For non-native speakers the terms `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft` might be confusing, however, since not everybody is familiar with the term `ragged`

Comment: I want it to be justified (Like the term used in microsoft word)

Comment: Your code is faulty, obviously the centered section (or chapter) title leaks out to the following text. But as you are not showing how you center the section  (or the chapter) it is not possible to tell you how to correct the code.

Comment: justified is the default but it looks like you have used `\centering` but as you have not shown an example, it is impossible to tell you where your code is wrong.

Comment: `\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\section{BACKGROUND}
%\subsection{SUBSECTION NAME 1}
\paragraph{} Researchers working in the field of image .
fdgdf,,...`

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/read/nvdqmqphbvnv
if this could help

Comment: kitty you still haven't shown any code that would produce the output you show, edit the code in the question so it does not stop at `\begin{document}` but makes a one page example with the layout in the image. Then someone can tell you how to fix it

Comment: We need code which we can compile to reproduce the problem. Right now, you've given us more preamble than we need, but nothing we need beyond that. Please edit your question to provide a minimal example which reproduces the issue. Off-topic: you are loading `hyperref` much too early and more than once (with different options). Also, it would be better to use `caption` to format the figure name rather than redefining `\figurename`.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a minimal example and post it in your question. However, you are using `\centering` in e.g. `title.tex` which might be the problem. Also, don't use `\paragraph{}` to start new paragraphs: that isn't what it does. And `\large`, `\Large` etc. are font switches - they don't take arguments. Also, never use `\\ ` to end a line outside of special environments (e.g. `tabular`, `center` etc.)

Comment: you need to post an example that _other people_ can copy and produce the effect, no-one can run your example as posted. meanwhile note that all over your soureces you use things like `\Large{Some text here}`  that is _completely wrong_ and will make the entire document text large, size commands do not take an argument so it should be `\Large some text here\par}` (but normally size commands should only be used in the definition of section headings, they should not be in your document at all)

Comment: The question is unclear, the code does not produce centered text, but justified default. The answer below just restates this, which makes the value of the answer a bit pointless, to be honest. I vote to close as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment!

After building an reduced compiling MWE from your given code I can not reproduce the layout you showed in your image.

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

    %adjust your page margins here
    \usepackage[top=0.70in, bottom=0.70in, left=0.8in,right=0.80in]{geometry} 
    \usepackage{graphicx} % <===========================================

    \usepackage{float} %used for figure placement with H as a parameter

    \usepackage{setspace}

    \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
    \def\figurename{\textbf{Figure }}

    %For the header and footer
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[L]{\emph{Fr.C.Rodrigues Institute of Technology, Vashi}} % except the center
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    }

    \pagestyle{fancy}

    \rhead{\emph{NAME OF PROJECT}}

    \fancyfoot[LO,LE]{\emph{Department of Electronics and Tlecommunication, FCRIT,Vashi}}
    \cfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RO, RE]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    %For the header and footer Over

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[% <=========================================================
  bookmarks,  
  colorlinks=false
]{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{%
  %pdfborder = {0 0 0}
%}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\lhead{ }

\pagenumbering{roman} %numbering before main content starts

%To reset the Header & Footer for TOC and LOF
\pagestyle{empty}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\tableofcontents % adds Index Page

\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\listoffigures % adds List of Figures
\cleardoublepage

%And reset back the settings we choose for Header and Footer
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} %reset numbering to normal for the main content

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\section{BACKGROUND}
%\subsection{SUBSECTION NAME 1}
\paragraph{} \Blindtext

\end{document}
```

I get the following resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Now please copy my MWE and add one of your `\input`ed files to it. Compile and check if the layout has changed ...

With your given code I can not recreate your given layout, so the reason for that layout is hidden in one of your previous `\input`ed files. We do not have this files, only you can know ...